# onload popup window open every time when i refresh the browser

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        var id = '#dialog';

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

});
```

I used this code for on-load popup box but when i refresh my browser every time show this popup box not 1 time, please tell me right way.

Comment: Isn't this Queness's jQuery modal window script?

Comment: No this is just simple modal popup box.

Comment: @AnmolRatanMohla [The code is way too similar](http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial) to be something else.. same variable names, same values..

Comment: @Daedalus You gave the link, and I gave the title! LoL..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of cookies to set the for the first time. So, wrap everything in a function, say, `showPopup();` and call the code this way, after adding [**jQuery.cookie**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$.cookie('showPopup')) {
    showPopup();
    $.cookie('showPopup', 'yes')
  }
});
```

Comment: please give me an example.

Comment: Yes, you are right Mr. Praveen but tell me where i add my id or class like:  #dialog

Comment: I don't get you. Right now, you need to copy the full contents of the `$(document).ready(function() {});` inside a function named `showPopup()` and then call it this way.

Comment: sorry but i am confused mr. praveen, showpopup not a id or class, then how to open my popup window.

Comment: You said that just with `$(document).ready(function() {});` you were able to show the popup right?

Comment: Could you give me example site link they are using onload popup box?

Comment: @AnmolRatanMohla Those doesn't work for you, even then, go for any government sites, and they have popups lying all around. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set any variable using this event , and used it in your code.

```
window.onunload = function(){
alert("unload event detected!");
```

}

Comment: I am realy sorry but, my client give me this code and request me use this code.

Comment: Please ready my code above mention, and if you add something, give me full code.